# How to return a value from an event to another event?

Tags: java, swing, events, return

I am new to Java Swing, I am writing code and I want to return the value of `d3` into the other event.

Can anybody tell me how to return that?

```
 private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 

{                                            

    double d1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    double d2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
    double d3 = d1 * d2;
    jTextField4.setText(d3 + "");
}                                           

private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    double d4 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText());
    double d5 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
    double d6 = d4 * d5;
    jTextField6.setText(d6 + "");
  }
```

Comment: pleas why double from integer, thats parsed from String, use JFornattedTextFied or JSpinner with number formatter, then the life will be easier,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use what is known as a global variable, declare a variable like:

```
int d3=0;
private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}
.....your code....
```